# How to return max date per month for user

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery, top-n

I have following table:

[image: table1]

And I would like to have returned maximum threshold date per each month for every user, so my final result should look like that:

[image: table2]

I wanted to use analytic function ROW_NUMBER and return maximum number of row but how to do it per month for each user? Is there any simpler way to do it in BigQuery?

Comment: There are multiple rows for the threshold date.  How are you choosing the one you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can partition the `row_number` by the user and the month, and then take the first one for each:

```sql
SELECT user_id, threshold_date, net_deposists_usd
FROM   (SELECT user_id, threshold_date, net_deposists_usd,
               ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, EXTRACT (MONTH FROM threshold_date)
                                   ORDER BY net_deposists_usd DESC) AS rk
        FROM   mytable)
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery now supports `qualify`, which does everything you want.  For the month, just use `date_trunc()`:

```
select t.*
from t
qualify row_number() over (partition by user_id, date_trunc(threshold_date, month) 
                           order by threshold_date desc, net_deposits_usd desc
                          );
```

A simple alternative uses arrays and `group by`:

```
select array_agg(t order by threshold_date desc, net_deposits_usd desc limit 1)[ordinal(1)].*
from t
group by user_id, date_trunc(threshold_date, month) ;
```